# Add Toolbar inside fragment (AndroidX)

Tags: android, android-fragments, androidx

I am trying to add ActionBar (Toolbar) inside fragment and then set Button to "end" of this action bar and add onClickListener on that button.

Cannot use support.v7.widget.ToolBar (I dont know why but I could not implement it)so I had to use androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar instead.
I could not find any source to follow.

app_bar_layout.xml:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_app_toolbar"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Fragment's design fragment_wall.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".WallFragment"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/update_wall_page_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_layout"></include>
</FrameLayout>
```

Code in WallFragment.java

```
public class WallFragment extends Fragment {


    public WallFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private Toolbar TopActivityToolbar;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wall, container, false);
        TopActivityToolbar = v.findViewById(R.id.update_wall_page_toolbar);

        TopActivityToolbar.setTitle("Príspevky");
        TopActivityToolbar.setLogo(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(),R.drawable.ic_add_circle_black_24dp));

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason for this behaviour ? As fragments resides inside an activity it's easier to add toolbar in activity

Comment: so what exactly is the issue?

Comment: Can you give a detailed description, where (in what fragment) do you need to set the button and if you need the App Bar in other fragments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so what was the successfull answer for me:

Inside **onCreate**  method just add *setHasOptionsMenu(true);*

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
```

Inside my *WallFragment.java* in **onCreateView** I added **setOnMenuItemClickListener** just right after initializing the Toolbar

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wall, container, false);

        TopActivityToolbar = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.update_wall_page_toolbar);
        TopActivityToolbar.setTitle("someTitle");
        TopActivityToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_app_actionbar_wall);

        // and finally set click listener
        TopActivityToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                // Your code inside Toolbar onClick...
                return false;
            }
        });
        return inflatedView;
    }
```

Do not forget to to **INFLATE** the menu from res/menu/...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to make it work you need to call this code in `onCreateView` callback of fragment that is needed to have a menu;

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Then you are able to inflate the menu and set listener to handle clicks on item:

```
inflater.inflate(*R.menu.your_menu_resource*, menu);
```

After that you are able to override `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected` to provide logic that is needed:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.toolbar_seetings) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Menu item was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

After that you just need to handle App Bar visibility, so you need to place the code in onCreateView and it will look like that:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the edited idea is actually really good. Im still trying do it the other way, but my app never reaches onCreateOptionMenu ... just onCreate and onCreateView

Comment: @Rasťo if you could specify what kind of behavior you want to get it would be easier to get an working solution.
I know that if you want to use menu you need to `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` to make it works.

Comment: Actually what you described was what I am looking for, I want Actionbar visible only in one fragment. This ActionBar has Title and one Button - to start another activity. I have setHasOptionMenu(true) inside onCreate but app never reach onCreateOptionMenu and thus the Button is unclicable

Comment: I'm now testing the code. After that if it works I will update answer. Upd: It works :D

Comment: I found a working solution but I am not sure if it is the best practise to use. I use Toolbar bar = v.findViewById() and then bar.setOnMenuItemClickListener()

Comment: Sounds like something less boilerplate and working, great job :D
I need to try that as well

Answer (score 0):

Add Toolbar inside fragment (AndroidX),you should use the **onCreateOptionsMenu()** method inside fragment.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(
      Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {inflater.inflate(R.menu.example_menu, menu);
}
```

First,you have to call **setHasOptionsMenu()** within the fragment's onCreate() method:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

//For handling item selection
You can handle menu item clicks in the **onOptionsItemSelected()** method:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.itemId:
        //action    
    return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Full Example code is below:**

In this example One activity: Main activity:
**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_id"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click"
        android:onClick="changeFragment"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FrameLayout frameLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        loadFragment(new FirstFragment());
    }
    private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_id, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    public void changeFragment(View view) {
        loadFragment(new SecondFragment());
    }
}
```

There is two fragment in this example:
FirstFragment and SecondFragment.

**FirstFragment.java** :

```
 public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout,container,false);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(
            Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.first_item_menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    //For handling item selection
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.itemId:
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"First Fragment item",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

**SecondFragment.java**

```
  public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_frag,container,false);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(
            Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.second_item_menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    //For handling item selection
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.itemId1:
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Second Fragment item",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

In menu file,**app:showAsAction="ifRoom"** in your menu item.
Below is example code for menu file.

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/itemId"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_apps_black_24dp"
        android:title="First"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom">
    </item>
</menu>
```